# Define bookmark in BIRT report so that it gets displayed in pdf output

Tags: birt

I am creating a BIRT report which fetches data from SQL. There are 4 different queries in the report which gives output in 4 different tables in report. I have added header(title) to each table (using insert text feature / lable feature) . My requirement is to include them (Title) in bookmark when that report is run in pdf output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify PDF bookmarks using the Table of Contents feature in BIRT.

The simplest way to do this is to select each table object in turn in the Layout tab, and in the *Table of Contents* section of the *Properties* tab within the *Property Editor* for the table, enter the desired bookmark text / title within double quotes (`"`).

Save and run the report in PDF format, and the specified TOC entries titles should appear as bookmarks.